# Giving focus after a href

Tags: html, css, focus

I want to know if there is a way to give the focus to an `input` after a local `href`

Like here's what I have :

```
<a href="#bottom"> Sign up </a>
And at the bottom of the page :
<div id="bottom">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email address">
</div>
```

What I want is when someone clics on the Sign Up it goes directly to the bottom page and gives focus to the `input` so the user can directly type his email address whitout having to clic.

Thanks !

Comment: CSS can detect the focus but it can't set it. For that you'd need JavaScript.

Comment: do `<a href="#email">Sign up</a>`

Comment: @GCyrillus : It doesn't do anything.

Comment: oups, you 're wright, i read too fast, you need javascript to trigger focus once bottom is targeted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `label` styled like an `a`.  Make sure the `label`'s `for` attribute matches the `input`'s `id` attribute.  This will focus the `input` when the `label` is clicked and scroll the page so the `input` is in view.

```css
.input-link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-link:hover,
.input-link:focus {
  color: red;
}

p {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<label class="input-link" for="email">Sign up</label>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae dolorum atque, eaque, modi ducimus commodi iure officia reprehenderit eius quasi eligendi natus aliquam dolore recusandae nobis. Perferendis inventore ea quisquam.</p>
<div id="bottom">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email address">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

**Updated** HTML: Added an id to the link

```
<a id="signUpLink" href="#bottom"> Sign up </a>
And at the bottom of the page :
<div id="bottom">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email address">
</div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $link = $("#signUpLink");
  var $emailInput = $("#email");

  $link.on("click", function(){
      $emailInput.focus();
  });
});
```

and here is the **fiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/yfs6nxmb/1/